# How to print only the numbers greater than the average?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and i'm trying to print my only numbers greater than the average from my file.

```
   3.2
   7.5
   1.11
   9.4
```

Average:4.8525

```
double x; 

 Scanner inputStream = null; 

 try { // place file in project folder, not src; 
     inputStream = new Scanner( new File("Data.txt") ); 
 } catch( FileNotFoundException e ) { 
     System.out.println("Error opening file"); 
     System.exit(1); 
 } 

 while(inputStream.hasNextDouble()){ 
     x = inputStream.nextDouble(); 
     System.out.println(x); 
 } 

 inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Have you started writing code even ? Whats wring with a If condition before printing ?

Comment: read the values into a list. calculate the average based on the values in the list. print the items in the list, only if they are greater than the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( inputStream.hasNextDouble() ){ 
 x = inputStream.nextDouble(); 
  if(x > 4.8525){
    System.out.println(x); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: i think the purpose of the exercise is to store all values, calculate the average, then print only those greater than the calculated average. (or read the file twice - but that would suck)

Answer (score 4):

1. At first you need to store data at `ArrayList`, if you don't know the size of data.

   ```
   List<Double> list=new ArrayList<>();
   while(inputStream.hasNextDouble()){ 
    list.add(inputStream.nextDouble());
   }
   ```
2. Calculate the sum of values.

   ```
    double sum=0.0;
    for(Double val: list){
      sum+= val;
    }
   ```
3. Iterate over list and print the value, which are greater than average.

   ```
    for(Double val: list){
     if(val> sum/list.size()){
     System.out.println(val);
     }
    }
   ```